# encrypt xls file in grails and download

Tags: grails, groovy, apache-poi, password-encryption

I need the xls file DOWNLOAD with a password or encryption.

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
import com.emmanuelrosa.frostedsheets.* 

def downloadxls(){
 /*
  * Creates a workbook with Apache POI and decorates it
  * with Frosted Sheets.
  */
    response.setContentType('application/vnd.ms-excel')
    response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'Attachment;Filename="data.xls"')

    // response.setContentType("APPLICATION/OCTET-STREAM")
    //  response.setHeader('Content-Disposition', 'Attachment;Filename="archivo.buf"')

    def outputStream = response.getOutputStream()
    def workbook = new FrostedWorkbook(new HSSFWorkbook())

    workbook['Students'].with {
        append(['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Age'])
        append(['John', 'Doe', '20'])
        append(['Jane', 'Smith', '18'])
    }

    workbook['Courses'].with {
        append(['Course Name', 'Number of Units'])
        append(['Algebra', 3])
        append(['English Grammar', 5])
    }
   /*
   * workbook is an instance of FrostedWorkbook, 
   * which implements the Workbook interface.
   * The writeProtectWorkbook() method is provided
   * by HSSFWorkbook (it's not in the interface).
   * FrostedWorkbook.workbook is the decorated HSSFWorkbook
   */

    workbook.workbook.writeProtectWorkbook('password', 'user')

    workbook.write(response.outputStream)
    outputStream << workbook

    outputStream.flush()
```

File download code.with this snippet of code I can download the .xls file but still not encrypted even if you add all data.

```
    outputStream.close()

}
```

the problem is that the file you download is not encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're attempting to use two libraries to create your Excel workbook: JXL and Apache POI. They do not know *anything* about each other. So JXL is ignoring the password.

### Excel workbook password protection

There's a difference between encryption and password protection. Both use passwords, but *password protection* does **not** encrypt the file. The file could still be read, but not modified.

Here's an example showing how to password-protect the workbook. I'm using my library [Frosted Sheets](https://bitbucket.org/erosa/frostedsheets/overview), which is a convenience wrapper around Apache POI.

```
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook
import com.emmanuelrosa.frostedsheets.* 

/*
 * Creates a workbook with Apache POI and decorates it
 * with Frosted Sheets.
 */
def workbook = new FrostedWorkbook(new HSSFWorkbook())

workbook['Students'] << [
    ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Age'],
    ['John', 'Doe', '20'],
    ['Jane', 'Smith', '18']
]

workbook['Courses'] << [
    ['Course Name', 'Number of Units'],
    ['Algebra', 3],
    ['English Grammar', 5]
]

/*
 * workbook is an instance of FrostedWorkbook, 
 * which implements the Workbook interface.
 * The writeProtectWorkbook() method is provided
 * by HSSFWorkbook (it's not in the interface).
 * FrostedWorkbook.workbook is the decorated HSSFWorkbook
 */
workbook.workbook.writeProtectWorkbook('password', 'user')
workbook.write(response.outputStream)
```

### Excel workbook encryption

*FrostedSheets* now provides encryption for XLSX workbooks. You just need to use version 0.3.0 or greater:

```
import com.emmanuelrosa.frostedsheets.* 

/*
 * Creates an XLSX workbook with Apache POI and decorates it
 * with Frosted Sheets.
 */
def workbook = FrostedWorkbook.createXLSX()

workbook['Students'] << [
    ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Age'],
    ['John', 'Doe', '20'],
    ['Jane', 'Smith', '18'],
]

workbook['Courses'] << [
    ['Course Name', 'Number of Units'],
    ['Algebra', 3],
    ['English Grammar', 5]
]
    
workbook.writeEncrypted(outputStream: response.outputStream, password: 'password')
```

**WARNING:** During the encryption process the workbook is written out unencrypted to temporary storage. The default is a byte array (RAM), but it's also possible to use a temporary file.

Also, make sure to change the file extension in the response header to *xlsx*.

Comment: BTW, in the future, please ask one question at a time. The Excel bit and the response are two separate questions  :)

Comment: thanks for answering the question . I have this problem with your code. org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.SheetConditionalFormatting

Comment: I don't understand. What's the problem exactly?

Comment: does not recognize the following line of code. workbook['Students'].with {

Comment: Hmm, that doesn't make sense. Can you add an update with your actual code? I'm assuming you've already added the Frosted Sheets dependency, cause it wouldn't have even compiled without it.

Comment: hello 've already solved the problem was due to the version of apache poi I had. I have even created the sheet. but this is not encrypted.I've updated the code.

Comment: I don't see your new code. Besides, I demonstrated password protection rather than encryption. I could not figure out how to get encryption working. The instructions are... cryptic.

Comment: I've uploaded the modified code . You can show me please because my xls file is not encrypted.

Comment: OK, @d-sanxhez. My example does NOT encrypt the file. That's why your file is not encrypted. My example demonstrates **password protection**. I did not demonstrate **encryption** because I could not figure out how to do it. Password protection and encryption are NOT the same thing.

Comment: thanks for answering. This well what I mean is that the downloaded file is not password protected

Comment: OK, I see what you're saying. When I opened the file with LibreOffice it opened in read-only mode. So yeah, since password protection applies only to editing, it's useless. Hmm...

Comment: You're right but the problem is that when you open the file with microsoft excel if I can edit without the password .

Comment: OK, I got workbook encryption to work :) I added instructions to my answer.

Comment: thanks for your reply. could please show me an example made ​​in grails of its encryption xlsx . as I have tried but apparently have the following problem. Could not initialize class org.apache.poi.POIXMLTypeLoader. I have version  compile 'org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:3.14-beta1'
    compile 'org.apache.poi:ooxml-schemas:1.3'.

Comment: @d-sanxhez, Here's a working example: https://bitbucket.org/erosa/encrypted-xlsxdownloader-demo/overview

Comment: hello thank you very much for responding effectively works to grails 3.1.1 . But I 'm using grails 2.4.3

Comment: thanks Emmanuel Rosa I am already in Grails Noob . dabo9373@gmail.com.

Comment: There's noone in Grails Noob registered with that email address. Regardless, I sent you an invite.